# wrong output for bubble sort feedback needed

Tags: c++

while testing of the program i found out it was giving wrong output. i have been trying to find the mistake but i cannot Please help.

// bubble.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort3 ( int x [ ] , int n ) {
    bool exchanges;
    int temp;
    do {
        n--; //make loop smaller each time
        exchanges = false; // assume this is last pass over array
        for ( int i=0; i < n-1; i++ ) {
            if (x [ i ] > x [ i+1 ]) {
                temp = x[ i ];
                x [ i ] = x [ i+1 ];
                x [ i+1 ] = temp;
                exchanges = true; // after exchange must look again
            } 
        } 
    }
    while (exchanges); 
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int array[4]={50,3,33,1};

    bubbleSort3 ( array , 4 );

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        cout << " "<< array[i]<< " ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
    system("pause");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My advice would be to get the debugger out and step through the code.

Comment: i have tried that but i cant find my mistake since i am new to programming

Comment: Then you have to keep at it. Stackoverflow is not a replacement for debugging.

Comment: Think about the implications of decrementing the `n` varible before/after the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line to for ( int i=0; i < n; i++ )
it will work

Comment: please accept the solution which works for you or at least up vote it

Answer (score 0):

Move the n-- after your for loop

```
void bubbleSort3 ( int x [ ] , int n ) {
    bool exchanges;
    int temp;
    do {
        exchanges = false; // assume this is last pass over array
        for ( int i=0; i < n-1; i++ ) {
            if (x [ i ] > x [ i+1 ]) {
                temp = x[ i ];
                x [ i ] = x [ i+1 ];
                x [ i+1 ] = temp;
                exchanges = true; // after exchange must look again
            }
        }
        n--; //make loop smaller each time
    }
    while (exchanges);
}
```